# code Coverage for Python testing for 3.4 on windows

Tags: python, testing, python-3.x, code-coverage

I want to try using `coverage.py` to test my python code. I'm using Python 3.4 and it says on Ned's site

> The latest version is coverage.py 3.7.1, released 13 December 2013. It is supported on Python versions 2.3 through 3.4

However, I can't find the Windows setup for 3.4. Do I have to install 3.3 to run the coverage? Since I tried with 3.3.5 and the setup for 3.3 said it didn't find Python registered, and is the 3.4 version only available on non-Windows platforms?

edit:

also tried 3.3.0 it still gives me a python not found in registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up re-installing Python 3.3.5 selecting the only me option, selecting all users will not register python in your user but it will register it in the Machine

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that I 'installed' coveragepy in the directory I want it in by unzipping a zip file.  It is not installed for any particular version.  coveragepy.**main** is clearly written to run on multiple versions of Python.  I run it with my (unregistered) repository build of 3.4 with a `cover.bat` file to test coverage of proposed idlelib test files.

```
@echo off
rem Usage: cover fileName [test_ suffix] # proper case required by coveragepy
rem filename without .py, 2nd parameter if test is not test_filename
setlocal
set py=34\pcbuild\python_d
set src=idlelib.%1
if "%2" EQU "" set tst=34/Lib/idlelib/idle_test/test_%1.py
if "%2" NEQ "" set tst=34/Lib/idlelib/idle_test/test_%2.py

%py% coveragepy run --pylib --source=%src% %tst%
%py% coveragepy report --show-missing
%py% coveragepy html
htmlcov\34_Lib_idlelib_%1.html
```

I have been quite pleased with `coveragepy` combined with a customized `.coveragerc` and the above.